# How to use Bootstrap's class collapse with linear transition?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying for a while to use boostrap collapse, but I would like a linear effect. I tried some versions of bootstrap and they have a very similar transition. I opted for the latest version of the site. I tried editing with CSS, but I was not successful.

I left the result that I got in the image below.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
  <title>Collapse</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="my-container">
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#collapseExample"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="collapseExample"
    >
      Button with data-bs-target
    </button>
    <div class="collapseExample" id="collapseExample">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores dolore quas nisi iste rerum, perferendis a
        quod enim aspernatur quam facilis unde reprehenderit. Fugit animi repellendus blanditiis nam ducimus dolorum!
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores dolore quas nisi iste rerum, perferendis a
        quod enim aspernatur quam facilis unde reprehenderit. Fugit animi repellendus blanditiis nam ducimus dolorum!
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores dolore quas nisi iste rerum, perferendis a
        quod enim aspernatur quam facilis unde reprehenderit. Fugit animi repellendus blanditiis nam ducimus dolorum!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="activies">
      <h1>Activies</h1>
      <div class="table-scroll">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Animal</th>
              <th scope="col">Age</th>
              <th scope="col">Weight</th>
              <th scope="col">Distance</th>
              <th scope="col">Link</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor"
                    class="bi bi-link-45deg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                      d="M4.715 6.542 3.343 7.914a3 3 0 1 0 4.243 4.243l1.828-1.829A3 3 0 0 0 8.586 5.5L8 6.086a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-.154.199 2 2 0 0 1 .861 3.337L6.88 11.45a2 2 0 1 1-2.83-2.83l.793-.792a4.018 4.018 0 0 1-.128-1.287z">
                    </path>
                    <path
                      d="M6.586 4.672A3 3 0 0 0 7.414 9.5l.775-.776a2 2 0 0 1-.896-3.346L9.12 3.55a2 2 0 1 1 2.83 2.83l-.793.792c.112.42.155.855.128 1.287l1.372-1.372a3 3 0 1 0-4.243-4.243L6.586 4.672z">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td>
                <a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Cat</td>
              <td>2a3m</td>
              <td>8kg</td>
              <td>4km</td>
              <td><a href="#">x </a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.my-container {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 80vw;
}

#collapseExample {
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 1s linear !important;
}

.activies {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your case because of `display:flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` this two property making the jump of `activity` class once the collapse is opened. Actually your collapse is working fine, the activity class is the one which making sudden jump at the end. Here I have done some modifications on css which might help your case. Hope this is what you are expecting as well.

```
.my-container {
background-color: white;
/* display: flex; */
flex-direction: column;
height: 60vh;
width: 80vw;
overflow: auto;
}



button {
    width: 100%;
    }

#collapseExample {
    background-color: red;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
   }

.activies {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: height 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

Change these part in your css alone will work. Hope this helps. If not please feel free to comment. Thanks